# Error Trying to delete s3 object with ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, aws-sdk

Trying to delete a s3 object by using ruby with something like this:

```
 After('@removeS3Files') do
  prefix = 'pifiles/files/'

  s3 = AWS::S3.new
  bucket = s3.buckets['scratching']

  if (defined?(s3files)).nil?
    s3files = []
  end

  s3files << bucket.objects.with_prefix(prefix).collect(&:key)
  s3files.each do |key|
    bucket.objects.delete(key)
  end
end
```

I'm getting the error "Failed to delete 1 objects (AWS::S3::Errors::BatchDeleteError)"

Comment: Try catching the exception and printing the errors for more information. 

Something like:

```begin;
  s3files.each do |key|
    bucket.objects.delete(key)
  end
rescue AWS::S3::Errors::BatchDeleteError => e;
   puts e.error_counts;
end
```